# How do I set the path of a goal while building a Maven project?

Tags: node.js, eclipse, maven, npm

I am trying to install node and npm to a particular location but the path is automatically set to "C:/Users.../webapp/node/node.exe" and node directory doesn't exist.
So I was wondering if there was a way in which I could change the path so that I could install everything in the right place.

Here is the command prompt message that appears when I run the Maven build:
--- frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ webside ---
[INFO] Installing node version v8.12.0
[INFO] Copying node binary from C:\Users\Q1011804.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\node\8.12.0\node-8.12.0-win-x64.exe to C:\Users\Q1011804\eclipse-workspace\par
ent\webside\src\main\webapp\node\node.exe
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project webside: Could not install Node.js: C:\Users\Q1011804\eclipse-workspace\parent\webside\src\main\webapp\node\node.exe (The system cannot find the path specified) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add

```
<configuration>
     <installDirectory>someDir</installDirectory>
</configuration>
```

to your plugin definition in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can add installation directory in path variable in `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <environment.path>C:\test\nodejs;%PATH%</environment.path>
</properties>
```

In the plugin you can specify it `environmentVariables`.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>npm install (initialize)</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <configuration>
        <executable>npm</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>run</argument>
          <argument>init:ci</argument>
        </arguments>
        <environmentVariables>
          <PATH>${environment.path}</PATH>
        </environmentVariables>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```